# Not printing all rows in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a movie database for private purposes. As a part of the database I want to be able to show the movies by sorting by genre, starting letter of movies or just show all.

I want to display the hits in a three column table until all rows in the database table have been printed.

For example:

```
Ice age 1     Ice age 2     Ice age 3

Die Hard 1    Die Hard 2    Die hard 3
```

What happens with the code below (Which is used when all movies should be shown) is that it stops after 39 rows even though I know it's 50 rows, mysql_num_rows() returns 50 and when I just printed the complete db table in 1 column I got 50 rows.

```
$counterone = 0;
  $countertwo = 0;
  if ($_movietype == 'showmeeverything')
  {
    $movieresult = mysql_query("SELECT url,title FROM movies ORDER BY title");
    if(mysql_num_rows($movieresult) == 0)
    {
        nomovie();
    }

    echo '<p align="center"><a href="index.php">Go back</a></p>';
    echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding=2" align="center">';
    echo '<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><b>Title</b></td></tr>';

    echo mysql_num_rows($movieresult);
    while ($counterone < mysql_num_rows($movieresult))
    {
        $counterone++;
        echo '<tr>';
        while (($result = mysql_fetch_array($movieresult)) && $countertwo < 3)
        {
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<a href="'.$result['url'].'">' . $result['title'] . '</a>';
            echo '</td>';
            $countertwo++;
        }
    echo '</tr>';
    $countertwo = 0;
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<p align="center"><a align="center" href="index.php">Go back</a></p>';
  }
```

Comment: Is it every 4th movie that is skipped?  My guess is that in your nested while loop  `$result = mysql_fetch_array( $movieresult )` moves the pointer regardless of whether or not you enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing `$counterone` in the right spot. You're counting table ROWS, but are working off number of records. $counterone should be inside the internal `while($result)` loop. And once it's there, $countertwo is redundant.

Try this instead:

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($movieresult)) {
   if ($counter % 3 == 0)
       echo '<tr>';
   }
   echo "<td> blah blah blah </td>";
   if ($counter % 3 == 2) {
       echo '</tr>';
   }
   $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$counterone = 0;
$countertwo = 0;
if ($_movietype == 'showmeeverything')
 {
 $movieresult = mysql_query("SELECT url,title FROM movies ORDER BY title");
 if(mysql_num_rows($movieresult) == 0)
{
    nomovie();
}

echo '<p align="center"><a href="index.php">Go back</a></p>';
echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding=2" align="center">';
echo '<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><b>Title</b></td></tr>';

echo mysql_num_rows($movieresult);
$numrows =  mysql_num_rows($movieresult);
while ($counterone < $numrows)
{
    $counterone++;
    echo '<tr>';
    while (($result = mysql_fetch_array($movieresult)) && $countertwo < 3)
    {
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<a href="'.$result['url'].'">' . $result['title'] . '</a>';
        echo '</td>';
        $countertwo++;
    }
echo '</tr>';
$countertwo = 0;
}
echo '</table>';
echo '<p align="center"><a align="center" href="index.php">Go back</a></p>';
```

}